# ASP.NET MVC - Populate Commonly Used Dropdownlists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I was wondering what the best practice is when populating commonly used dropdownlists in ASP.NET MVC. For instance, I have a Country and State select which is used often in my application. It seems dirty to populate viewmodel and bind to that viewmodel from my controller for every single view I want to contain such a dropdownlist.

How do people populate their dropdownlists in such cases? - custom baseclass with this baked in? Helper classes, etc?

Thanks in advance,

JP

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have a `RequiresStateList` attribute to inject that common functionality to the actions that need it.

```
public class RequiresStateList : ActionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext) 
    {
        filterContext.Controller.ViewData["StateList"] = GetStates();
    }
}
```

And your action

```
[RequiresStateList]
public ActionResult Index() {
    return View();
}
```

Now you can get that list from the ViewData in your view.

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of this - an elegant and reusable solution. Thanks!

Comment: In jest, I declare that this violates the Thunderdome Principle!

Comment: Great solution. First time I realised you can make custom attributes

Answer (score 3):

Custom HTML Helpers is the way to go...

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

Comment: Very elegant: Neither the model nor the view are bloated. The *code* in the view is elegant and reusable. The HtmlHelper can be separately unit tested.

Comment: I like this solution over having them in the models.  I prefer to keep my models to the data that is being populated/submitted, which in this case, would be the selected value -- not the complete list of values.  These also come in handy to allow your view templates to fetch the `Text` property of a selected value for DispalyFor templates (i.e. fetch me the Text property where Value property matches the selected value).

Comment: Extending HTML Helpers with DAL breaks MVC architecture, because you will be having your views calling to the data layer instead of it just being a dummy.

Though breaking MVC architecture is not necessarily a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of creating view models that match (model) each view exactly.  So if you have a view with a States dropdown list, my view model for that page would have a States collection of ListItems.

I wouldn't worry about having view models with a states collection on it.  Instead I'd centralize the logic to get the states, something like:

```
viewModel.States = StatesHelper.GetStates(); // returns IList<ListItem>
```

Comment: there is an interesting argument about this approach here: http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2010/10/populating-drop-down-lists-in-aspnet.html