# Should the model be responsible for holding lists that will ultimately populate dropdownlists in the view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

This might be similar to [ASP.NET MVC - Populate Commonly Used Dropdownlists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231144/asp-net-mvc-populate-commonly-used-dropdownlists).

I want to populate DropDownLists. Some of it is static data. Some of it comes from the Database. A couple of times I found myself forgetting to call the code that populates my lists and sets the ViewBag accordingly. It is almost worth adding a unit test for this. The only way I think that this suits a unit test is if you place it in model/service. Is there a best practice for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that the data is contained within the model but is perhaps constructed by a html.helper method. this way, you keep the plumbing markup out of the view and leave the controller free to invoke the neccesary view and model.

You could also of course hand it off to a partialview with an `<IList<SelectList>>` model.

cats and their skin :)

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the spirit of the pattern then the Model should supply the View with everything it needs to present to the user that's not static. If you have static dropdown lists then you could say that these could be constructed within the mark-up. If you are passing a `SelectList` to the View from your Action then I'd stick it in the Model to make things simpler and more coherent.

Answer (score 0):

My rule of thumb is that the data must somehow be in the model, either as a ready to use SelectList or at worst in some container that can easily be turned into a SelectList using a LINQ-to-object call.

The bottom line is that the view should never contain any non trivial code.

EDIT (answer to your comment): 
I try not to put too much code in models. Models are more like a simple bunch of data gathered by the controller and used by the view.

Regarding simple and/or common things such as the days of week, I believe an HTML helper is the most elegant solution. See [WayneC's answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231144/asp-net-mvc-populate-commonly-used-dropdownlists/4231167#4231167).

Comment: It was more of a question of the controller vs the model? If it is a simple list, for example days of the week? Model or the controller? I think if it is something more domain related it should be in the model.