# Populate Dropdown list according to the value of another dropdown list in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my model I have the following:

```
public RegisterModel()
    {
        CountryList = new SelectList(new BusinessLayer.Countries().getAllCountries(), "ID", "Name");
        TownList = new SelectList(new BusinessLayer.Towns().getTownsByCountry(CountryList.SelectedValue.ToString() != null ? CountryList.SelectedValue.ToString() : "1"), "ID", "Name");
    }
```

View:

```
 <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country, Model.CountryList,1)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Country)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Town)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Town, Model.TownList)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Town)
            </div>
```

By default the country list is being populated by the 1st ID retreived from the datase. How can I display all the towns which have a Country ID of the Country dropdown Selected value like I am trying to do in the model?

Comment: Why not you consider to use a jquery or js based plugin for this. one good one is http://jquery-plugins.net/jquery-cascading-dropdown-plugin i think only thing you need to do is expose to method for returning dropdown values. first one is of course the country and second one for city which might take a countryid or something that sort

Comment: I think, you should use jquery/angularjs cascading dropdown here

Comment: @qamar , is it not possible to achieve without using jquery?

Comment: Yes. it should be. but you still need to make a bit of javascript on the change event of first dropdownlist selection change event. On selection change you need to call a JS function which in turn will call your controller action which shall take a country id and return you new data. Once you have city data returned then you can bind it to the second list using some javascript again. But with a plugin these codes will be much cleaner and easier. Choice is yours

Answer (score 1):

Refer code below. This should help you proceed further on this.

MODEL

```
namespace MvcApplicationrazor.Models
{
    public class CountryModel
    {
        public List<State> StateModel { get; set; }
        public SelectList FilteredCity { get; set; }
    }
    public class State
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string StateName { get; set; }
    }
    public class City
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int StateId { get; set; }
        public string CityName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            CountryModel objcountrymodel = new CountryModel();
            objcountrymodel.StateModel = new List<State>();
            objcountrymodel.StateModel = GetAllState();
            return View(objcountrymodel);
        }


        //Action result for ajax call
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetCityByStaeId(int stateid)
        {
            List<City> objcity = new List<City>();
            objcity = GetAllCity().Where(m => m.StateId == stateid).ToList();
            SelectList obgcity = new SelectList(objcity, "Id", "CityName", 0);
            return Json(obgcity);
        }
        // Collection for state
        public List<State> GetAllState()
        {
            List<State> objstate = new List<State>();
            objstate.Add(new State { Id = 0, StateName = "Select State" });
            objstate.Add(new State { Id = 1, StateName = "State 1" });
            objstate.Add(new State { Id = 2, StateName = "State 2" });
            objstate.Add(new State { Id = 3, StateName = "State 3" });
            objstate.Add(new State { Id = 4, StateName = "State 4" });
            return objstate;
        }
        //collection for city
        public List<City> GetAllCity()
        {
            List<City> objcity = new List<City>();
            objcity.Add(new City { Id = 1, StateId = 1, CityName = "City1-1" });
            objcity.Add(new City { Id = 2, StateId = 2, CityName = "City2-1" });
            objcity.Add(new City { Id = 3, StateId = 4, CityName = "City4-1" });
            objcity.Add(new City { Id = 4, StateId = 1, CityName = "City1-2" });
            objcity.Add(new City { Id = 5, StateId = 1, CityName = "City1-3" });
            objcity.Add(new City { Id = 6, StateId = 4, CityName = "City4-2" });
            return objcity;
        }
```

VIEW

```
@model MvcApplicationrazor.Models.CountryModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function GetCity(_stateId) {
        var procemessage = "<option value='0'> Please wait...</option>";
        $("#ddlcity").html(procemessage).show();
        var url = "/Test/GetCityByStaeId/";

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { stateid: _stateId },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                var markup = "<option value='0'>Select City</option>";
                for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                    markup += "<option value=" + data[x].Value + ">" + data[x].Text + "</option>";
                }
                $("#ddlcity").html(markup).show();
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
        });

    }
</script>
<h4>
 MVC Cascading Dropdown List Using Jquery</h4>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StateModel, new SelectList(Model.StateModel, "Id", "StateName"), new { @id = "ddlstate", @style = "width:200px;", @onchange = "javascript:GetCity(this.value);" })
    <br />
    <br />
    <select id="ddlcity" name="ddlcity" style="width: 200px">

    </select>

    <br /><br />
  }
```

[asp-net-mvc-populate-commonly-used-dropdownlists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231144/asp-net-mvc-populate-commonly-used-dropdownlists)

[fill-drop-down-list-on-selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013644/fill-drop-down-list-on-selection-of-another-drop-down-list)